# JAXB Parsing an XML file with variables (e.g. $(var1) )

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I'm interested to parse an XML that contains variables (which are defined by me inside the XML).

Here's an example of the XML files:

```
   <parameters>
          <parameter name="parent-id" value="1" />
          <parameter name="child-id" value="1" />
   </parameters>

   <Parents>
          <Parent id="$(parent-id)">
                 <Children>
                       <Child id="$(child-id)">
                       </Child>
                 </Children>
          </Parent>
   </Parents>
```

Is there a utility or some standard way to do so in Java? (using JAXB possibly)
Or should I implement this "mini" parsing mechanism by myself?
(A mechanism that identifies the variables and plants them inside the XML, and only later calls JAXB flows)

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Problem 1: that's not a valid XML file because it doesn't have a root element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an XSLT transformation to convert your XML into an XSLT stylesheet and then execute the XSLT stylesheet. It's simple enough to convert

```
 <parameters>
          <parameter name="parent-id" value="1" />
          <parameter name="child-id" value="1" />
   </parameters>
```

into

```
  <xsl:param name="parent-id" select="1" />
  <xsl:param name="child-id" select="1" />
```

and

```
<Parent id="$(parent-id)">
```

into

```
<Parent id="{$parent-id}">
```

and to add a wrapper `xsl:stylesheet` and `xsl:template` element, and then you're done.